# Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String[]'

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net

Have you got another idea to get this list of data?

I would like to show all my code because I think this can be much more easier for you. In this code you can see how I connect with role file.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using Microsoft.Interop.Security.AzRoles;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Collections.Generic;




namespace Authman
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            // See the following table for other sample connection strings.
            string connectionString = @"msxml://c:\plik.xml";

            AzAuthorizationStoreClass azStore = new AzAuthorizationStoreClass();
            azStore.Initialize(0, connectionString, null);

            IAzApplication2 azApplication = azStore.OpenApplication2("SatheeshApp", null);

            IAzClientContext3 clientContext = (IAzClientContext3)azApplication.InitializeClientContextFromToken((ulong)WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token, null);


            // Use the default application scope.
            string[] roles = (string[])clientContext.GetRoles("");


            foreach (string role in roles)
            {
                Span3.InnerHtml += role.ToString() + "</br>";
            }



        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is `clientContext` declared as?

Comment: You can try `clientContext.GetRoles("").Select(r => r.ToString()).ToArray();` , although i have also no idea what `clientContext.gGetRoles` returns.

Comment: What is the return type of GetRoles? Looks like it's returning an `Object[]` in this message, while in your errors listed below it returns `Object`...?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Error Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Authman\Authman\WebForm1.aspx.cs 36 30 Authman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just cast to the object[] the error indicates it to be instead;

```
object[] roles = (object[])clientContext.GetRoles("");

foreach(object role in roles)
{
    Span3.InnerHtml += role.ToString() + "</br>";
}
```

Comment: Error Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'object[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Authman\Authman\WebForm1.aspx.cs 38 30 Authman

Comment: @RafalPolandBeginner Seems the return type is object, but it actually contains an object[], try my edit above.

Comment: thx for help your answer was correct now application showing me all roles for my user -Menager - Finance Menager - HR Menager :) from active directory

Answer (score 4):

Use the `Cast<string>()` method.  This is related to covariance/contravariance.  You need to cast each item in the array (which is what the `Cast` method does) rather than the entire array.  If you really need to convert it into another string array you can use the `ToArray` method, but since here you're just using a `foreach` on it there is no need.

```
foreach(string role in clientContext.GetRoles("").Cast<string>())
{
  //use role
}
```

You'll need to add a `using System.Linq` to get the `Cast` extension method.

Comment: Errors Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and the best extension method overload 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast<TResult>(System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Authman\Authman\WebForm1.aspx.cs 35 37 Authman

Comment: Error 2 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection' C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Authman\Authman\WebForm1.aspx.cs 35 37 Authman

Comment: So what do you think you should do?  What is that error message saying to you?

Comment: I will be honest with you I'm sitting with this problem a lot of time but I will be honest with you I have not idea where is problem.

Comment: What does the method `GetRoles` return, what type?

Comment: Object IAzClientContext3.GetRoles([string bstrScopeName =””])

Comment: So you're returning an object but what it really is is an object array.  How do you change it from an object to an object array?

Comment: thx for your time and your help - now all system working correct :)

Answer (score 4):

```
string[] roles = clientContext.GetRoles("").Cast<string>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Errors:Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and the best extension method overload 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast<TResult>(System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Authman\Authman\WebForm1.aspx.cs 36 30 Authman

Comment: Are you sure `clientContext.GetRoles("")` is returning an array of `Object` and not just a single `Object`?

Comment: I`m sure you have got this in picture. Application import Roles from Active Directory

Comment: I have the same question as @SteveDanner, look this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15208254/stackoverflow/objectarray.jpg

Comment: I agree with @OscarJara, it seems like something isn't right with the `GetRoles` call.  Either his answer or mine should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Linq;

string[] roles = someObjectArray.OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Errors: string[] roles = clientContext.GetRoles("").OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray(); Error:Error 2 'object' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and no extension method 'OfType' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Authman\Authman\WebForm1.aspx.cs 38 57 Authman

Comment: look this, in this example I convert int to string from object array: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15208254/stackoverflow/objectarray.jpg Maybe your clientContext.GetRoles("") is not well declared.

Answer (score 2):

```
object[] roles=clientContext.GetRoles("");
foreach(object role in roles)
{
   Span3.InnerHtml + = role.ToString() + "</br>";
}
```

Why you need to cast your array to `string[]`? You can use it without casting at all.

Comment: Errors: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'object[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Authman\Authman\WebForm1.aspx.cs 38 30 Authman

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, `clientContext.GetRoles("").Cast<string>().ToArray()` is the work around.

Lets say what happens if the conversion is legal. you have a List listOfAnimals.

```
List<Cow> listOfCows = GetListOfCows();

listOfAnimals = listOfCows;

//After some lines of code

List<Tiger> listOfTiger = GetListOfTigers();

listOfAnimals.Add(listOfTiger); //Epic fail.
```

You might have accidentally added `Tiger` to a list of `Cow`. Which is wrong and dangerous. The CLR does not allow you to introduce such bugs in to the code.